# Sort an list of timestamps to another lists

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm getting a list of of timestamps from a server.

How can I sort them by date and regroup the list to new lists by their dates with JavaScript.

The problem is, I'm not sure how many different dates will arrive from the server.

I want to create a new row in a HTML table for each date

The Data I get and what I tried

```js
"timeActivities": [{
    "start": "2021-06-01T06:00:41.928+00:00",
    "end": "2021-06-01T15:00:41.928+00:00",
    "activityType": "Work"
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-06-02T06:00:32.928+00:00",
    "end": "2021-06-02T15:00:15.928+00:00",
    "activityType": "Work"
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-06-03T06:00:16.928+00:00",
    "end": "2021-06-03T15:00:12.928+00:00",
    "activityType": "Work"
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-06-04T06:00:01.928+00:00",
    "end": "2021-06-04T15:00:02.928+00:00",
    "activityType": "Work"
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-06-05T06:00:03.928+00:00",
    "end": "2021-06-05T15:00:00.928+00:00",
    "activityType": "Work"
  }
]



function addTimeToWorkHourTable(datesArr) {

  //Clears the table head
  $("#tblWorkedHours tr").empty();
  $("#tblTimeSchedule tbody").empty();


  var rowCounter = 0;
  var columnCounter = 0;
  var tempArr = []
  //Counts rows and Colums, was needed in a later version
  for (var i = 0; i < datesArr.length; i++) {

    if (i + 1 != datesArr.length) {
      tempArr.push(datesArr[i + 1])
      var tempDate1 = new Date(datesArr[i]['start'])
      var tempDate2 = new Date(tempArr[i]['start'])
    } else {
      tempArr.push(datesArr[0])

      var tempDate1 = new Date(datesArr[i]['start'])
      var tempDate2 = new Date(tempArr[0]['start'])
    }

    if (tempDate1.getDate() != tempDate2.getDate()) {
      rowCounter++;
    } else {
      columnCounter++;
    }
  }

  //Creating a checkDate to find different dates
  var checkDate = new Date(datesArr[0]['start'])
  var firstColumn = true;
  var columnEnd = false;
  var oneDay = 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var hoursWorkedPerDay = 0;
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("employmentType") === "FULLTIME") {
    var targetWorkHoursPerDay = 8;
  } else {
    var targetWorkHoursPerDay = 4;
  }
  var difference;
  var tempHourStart
  var tempHourEnd
  for (var i = 0; i < datesArr.length; i++) {

    var tempDate = new Date(datesArr[i]['start'])

    if (checkDate.getDate() === tempDate.getDate() && i + 1 != datesArr.length) {

      if (firstColumn) {
        var newRow = "<tr>";
        var newRowSchedule = "<tr>";
        newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-calendar\"></i>" + dateFormmater(tempDate) + "</td>";
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-calendar\"></i>" + dateFormmater(tempDate) + "</td>";
        if (firstDateOfDay != null) {
          newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-play-circle\"style=\"color: #00FF00;\"></i>" + firstDateOfDay.getHours() + ":" + firstDateOfDay.getMinutes() + ":" + firstDateOfDay.getSeconds() + "</td>";
          newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-stop-circle\" style=\"color: #FF0000;\"></i>" + firstDateOfDay.getHours() + ":" + firstDateOfDay.getMinutes() + ":" + firstDateOfDay.getSeconds() + "</td>";
        }
        firstDateOfDay = null;
        firstColumn = false;
      }
      tempHourStart = new Date(datesArr[i]['start']);
      tempHourEnd = new Date(datesArr[i]['end']);

      hoursWorkedPerDay += Math.abs((tempHourEnd.getTime() - tempHourStart.getTime()) / (oneDay));
      newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-play-circle\"style=\"color: #00FF00;\"></i>" + tempHourStart.getHours() + ":" + tempHourStart.getMinutes() + ":" + tempHourStart.getSeconds() + "</td>";
      newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-stop-circle\" style=\"color: #FF0000;\"></i>" + tempHourEnd.getHours() + ":" + tempHourEnd.getMinutes() + ":" + tempHourEnd.getSeconds() + "</td>";


      //When the Date changes, we add the Row to the table
    } else if (checkDate.getDate() != tempDate.getDate()) {

      columnEnd = true;
      if (columnEnd) {
        difference = (hoursWorkedPerDay - targetWorkHoursPerDay);
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-history\"></i>" + convertNumToTime(hoursWorkedPerDay) + "</td>";
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-bullseye\"></i>" + convertNumToTime(targetWorkHoursPerDay) + "</td>";
        if (difference < 0) {
          newRowSchedule += "<td style=\"background-color:#FF0000;\">" + convertNumToTime(difference) + "</td>";
        } else {
          newRowSchedule += "<td style=\"background-color:#00FF00;\">" + convertNumToTime(difference) + "</td>";
        }
        newRow += "</tr>";
        $("#tblWorkedHours tbody").append(newRow);
        $("#tblTimeSchedule tbody").append(newRowSchedule);
        var firstDateOfDay = tempDate;
        checkDate = tempDate;
        firstColumn = true;
        columnEnd = false;
      }

    }

    //We use this if the last 2 dates are the same
    if (checkDate.getDate() === tempDate.getDate() && i + 1 === datesArr.length) {

      tempHourStart = new Date(datesArr[i]['start']);
      tempHourEnd = new Date(datesArr[i]['end']);

      //TODO Fix this bullshit MF

      if (firstColumn) {
        var newRow = "<tr>";
        var newRowSchedule = "<tr>";
        newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-calendar\"></i>" + dateFormmater(tempDate) + "</td>";
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-calendar\"></i>" + dateFormmater(tempDate) + "</td>";
        firstColumn = false;
      }

      hoursWorkedPerDay += Math.abs((tempHourEnd.getTime() - tempHourStart.getTime()) / (oneDay));

      newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-play-circle\"style=\"color: #00FF00;\"></i>" + tempHourStart.getHours() + ":" + tempHourStart.getMinutes() + ":" + tempHourStart.getSeconds() + "</td>";
      newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-stop-circle\" style=\"color: #FF0000;\"></i>" + tempHourEnd.getHours() + ":" + tempHourEnd.getMinutes() + ":" + tempHourEnd.getSeconds() + "</td>";

      columnEnd = true;
      if (columnEnd) {

        difference = (hoursWorkedPerDay - targetWorkHoursPerDay);
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-history\"></i>" + convertNumToTime(hoursWorkedPerDay) + "</td>";
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-bullseye\"></i>" + convertNumToTime(targetWorkHoursPerDay) + "</td>";
        if (difference < 0) {
          newRowSchedule += "<td style=\"background-color:#FF0000;\">" + convertNumToTime(difference) + "</td>";
        } else {
          newRowSchedule += "<td style=\"background-color:#00FF00;\">" + convertNumToTime(difference) + "</td>";
        }
        newRow += "</tr>";
        $("#tblWorkedHours tbody").append(newRow);
        $("#tblTimeSchedule tbody").append(newRowSchedule);
        checkDate = tempDate;
        firstColumn = true;
        columnEnd = false;
      }

    }

    //We Check if the last date is uniqe on its own
    //if so we add a new row
    if (checkDate.getDate() != tempDate.getDate() && (i + 1) === datesArr.length) {

      tempHourStart = new Date(datesArr[i]['start']);
      tempHourEnd = new Date(datesArr[i]['end']);
      firstColumn = true;
      if (firstColumn) {
        var newRow = "<tr>";
        var newRowSchedule = "<tr>";
        newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-calendar\"></i>" + dateFormmater(tempDate) + "</td>";
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-calendar\"></i>" + dateFormmater(tempDate) + "</td>";
        firstColumn = false;

      }

      hoursWorkedPerDay += Math.abs((tempHourEnd.getTime() - tempHourStart.getTime()) / (oneDay));
      newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-play-circle\"style=\"color: #00FF00;\"></i>" + tempHourStart.getHours() + ":" + tempHourStart.getMinutes() + ":" + tempHourStart.getSeconds() + "</td>";
      newRow += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-stop-circle\" style=\"color: #FF0000;\"></i>" + tempHourEnd.getHours() + ":" + tempHourEnd.getMinutes() + ":" + tempHourEnd.getSeconds() + "</td>";

      columnEnd = true;
      if (columnEnd) {
        difference = (hoursWorkedPerDay - targetWorkHoursPerDay);
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + hoursWorkedPerDay + "</td>";
        newRowSchedule += "<td>" + "<i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-bullseye\"></i>" + convertNumToTime(targetWorkHoursPerDay) + "</td>";
        if (difference < 0) {
          newRowSchedule += "<td style=\"background-color:#FF0000;\">" + convertNumToTime(difference) + "</td>";
        } else {
          newRowSchedule += "<td style=\"background-color:#00FF00;\">" + convertNumToTime(difference) + "</td>";
        }
        newRow += "</tr>";

        $("#tblWorkedHours tbody").append(newRow);
        $("#tblTimeSchedule tbody").append(newRowSchedule);
        checkDate = tempDate;
        firstColumn = true;
        columnEnd = false;
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please fix it into a [mcve]

Comment: JSON is a text format. `datesArr` is presumably the parsed JSON and is therefore an array of objects, not JSON any more.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with _.groupBy in lodash